# how to exclude specific symbols from ls output in command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, ls

for example I have list of pdfs:
01_name1.pdf
02_name2.pdf
03_name3.pdf
04_name4.pdf
05_name5.pdf
06_name6.pdf
07_name7.pdf

how do I get this output from command line:
name1
name2
name3
name4
name5
name6
name7
Or what if I want to exclude only 3 of the first symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `cut`.

```bash
ls | cut -c4- | cut -d_ -f2 | cut -d. -f1
```

`ls` lists the files in the current directory.
`cut -c4-` removes the first 3 characters from each file name.
`cut -d_ -f2` uses the underscore as the delimiter and extracts the second field.
`cut -d. -f1` uses the dot as the delimiter and extracts the first field.